# Wordpress Custom Post Type Submenu Can't Access Constants or $this

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, submenu

Ok, I've got a custom post type in a plugin, and the plugin is structured as a class. I'm also setting some constants for the plugin as well.

I've created a submenu for the custom post type, but my problem is that when I access that page, it can't access the plugin constants or the class' $this variable. Help!

Here's my code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_psc_menu_page'));
function add_psc_menu_page(){
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=my-custom-post-type','Sub Menu','Sub Menu Title','manage_options','my-custom-post-type', array(&$this, 'render_psc_sub_page'));
}
function render_psc_sub_page(){
    include(PSC_PLUGIN_URL.'/util/custom-post-submenu-page.php');
}
```

And in the submenu php file, trying to access a variable I KNOW is set like:

```
$this->plugin_activated
```

blows up with this error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

and trying to access the plugin constants like

```
PSC_PLUGIN_URL
```

give an error:

```
Use of undefined constant PSC_PLUGIN_URL - assumed 'PSC_PLUGIN_URL'
```

I'm not sure how including the file in the submenu of a custom post throws things out of context, when I can create regular menus with no issues. However, I'd rather nest several menu items under the custom post type.

Could you point my in the right direction on how to get this submenu page to access $this and the rest of the plugin? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that your class has no instance. Try to redeclare methods and fields to ststatic and call them like in example: http://ideone.com/vGX0S2

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help since I've got variables that aren't static and shouldn't be public.


This also doesn't explain how if I create a brand new menu item, not a submenu, I can get the instance of the class and it's variables - it just doesn't work when I set this menu as a submenu of anything else - settings, page, custom post, etc.

The file's being included IN a function of the class and it can't access the variables and methods?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your menu should be an instance of this class, something like $menu = new YourClass(); $menu->add_submenu_page(args);